# list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: python, integer, divmod

I have a list, sortedInfected, which is made up of integers and with an unknown length.

When I run this script i get the error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not float".

How can i fix this?

```
medianList =[]
b = (len(sortedInfected) / 2)

if len(sortedInfected) % 2 == 0:

    median = (sortedInfected[b] + sortedInfected[b-1]) // 2
    medianList.append(median)
else:

    median = sortedInfected[b - 0.5]
    medianList.append(median)
```

Comment: If using Python 3, force integer division by using `//`.  But you are also subtracting `0.5` from `b`.  What do you expect this to do?  If `b` is `8`, and you subtract `0.5` from it, you are left with `7.5`.  How do you expect this to be used as a list index?

Comment: List indexes must be integers.  You need to decide how you want to handle the cases that currently give non-integer indexes.

Comment: My thought was that i only subtracted 0.5 from b when the length was odd. That's why i put it under "else". So if len is 9, b would be 9/2 - 0.5. But that did not work. But it seems to work with Cory's script, so it's all good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x, the `/` operator performs floating point division. If you want `int` division use `//`

```
b = len(sortedInfected) // 2
```

You could therefore change your code to

```
medianList =[]
b = (len(sortedInfected) // 2)

if len(sortedInfected) % 2 == 0:    
    median = (sortedInfected[b] + sortedInfected[b-1]) // 2
    medianList.append(median)
else:    
    median = sortedInfected[b]
    medianList.append(median)
```

Comment: That would only work if the len(sortedInfected) is an even number. How can I get it to work with odd numbers?